# How to add a FormToolbar with upload functionality to a custom form

Tags: sharepoint

I have a custom sharepoint form where I want to add a FormToolbar with upload functionality to it.

I added it like this

```
<SharePoint:FormToolBar runat="server" ID="ft" ControlMode="New" />
```

when I click on the attach file link it diplays a message saying "this form was customized not working with attachemnets".

I searched for this error and found that there is a fix and a method to make this work with a custom NewItem.aspx, the workaround was to modify the XSL.

My page is custom and has no XSL the fix is not applicable for me.

so is there a solution to this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This KB article may help:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953271 if you are using SharePoint Designer to create your custom form.  It sounds like you're using this approach (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543922.aspx) though.

Comment: less links, more content. copy the content here, leave links as reference. links can die, and then your answer is meaningless.